# dSYM file from device

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, decode

My application is crashing, and I cannot find an exact way how to reproduce the crash for two days. So, I would like to decode the dSYM file, and to see there what's the problem (hoping it helps). How can I get the dSYM file from the device?

Comment: open folder "Products" in navigator right click you app "xxxxx.app" and select "show in Finder" you find it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will probably need to get the dSYM from the Xcode build products.

1. Open the Xcode Organizer (in Xcode see Window -> Organizer)
2. Go to the Archives tab and select the crashing build of the relevant project
3. Select Distribute, then choose Export as Xcode Archive
4. Locate your exported archive (.xcarchive file), control-click on it and select View Package Contents
5. Your dSYM will be in the dSYMs subfolder of the Xcode Archive contents

But, a far easier way to get the stack trace is to either make the app crash while running in the iOS Simulator or on a tethered iOS device in Xcode (i.e. when running with Product -> Run in Xcode), or by connecting your device and viewing the desymbolicated crash reports in the Devices section of the Xcode Organiser Devices tab.

(The above all assumes that you've build the app in Xcode on a machine you can access and you've kept the archives for the build in the Xcode Organizer.)

For more information see Apple's tech note: [Understanding and Analyzing iOS Application Crash Reports](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html).

Comment: So what if archives is empty, even though you have crash logs on your device?

Comment: If you don't have the dSYMs you won't be able to desymbolicate the crash logs, and they won't be much use unfortunately.