# Unable to manually upload dSYM file to Firebase Crashlytics 4.0.0+

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I am running the latest Crashlytics pod on my iOS project and am no longer using Fabric. Since Firebase removed the option to upload a dSYM file I am stuck with figuring out how to upload my dSYM file manually.

My setup in Xcode is as followed:

- Installed Crashlytics via Cocoapods 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
- Under Target > Build Settings > Debug Information Format - I have set the options to **DWARF with dSYM File**
- Under Build Phases > Run Script - I have added "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"

  - Under the Input File Lists in Run Script - I have also added $(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)

---

My attempt to manually upload the file:

- Downloaded the dSYM from Apple Connect (Bitcode is enabled on my project)
- Open terminal and added the following (recommended by Firebase): 
  /path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols
  -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /path/to/dSYMs

---

**Issue:**

My path I've set in terminal:

- /Users/myhomefolder/Desktop/MyFolder/MyAppFolder/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /Users/myhomefolder/Desktop/MyFolder/MyAppFolder/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /Users/myhomefolder/Desktop/appDsyms

When I try to run the terminal with the path above, I get an error: /Desktop/MyFolder/MyAppFolder/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols: **No such file or directory**

I know my path to FirebaseCrashlytics is correct but I am not certain as to why I am unable to reach the upload-symbols path.

Is there is something I am missing?

---

Tried following guide on Firebase:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios&authuser=0

Tried solutions presented through these posts:

- [iOS and FirebaseCrashlytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60821249/ios-and-firebasecrashlytics)
- [upload dSYMs to Firebase using upload-symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61013943/upload-dsyms-to-firebase-using-upload-symbols)
- [Firebase Crashlytics: Upload missing dSYMs to see crashes from 1 versions.(iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296774/firebase-crashlytics-upload-missing-dsyms-to-see-crashes-from-1-versions-ios)
- [Why Crashlytics is asking for missing DSYM file every time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51440225/why-crashlytics-is-asking-for-missing-dsym-file-every-time)
- [How to run upload symbols to upload dSYMs as a part of Xcode build process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54577202/how-to-run-upload-symbols-to-upload-dsyms-as-a-part-of-xcode-build-process)

Answer (score 0):

use these:

- path of upload-symbols => /Users/yourhomefolder/Desktop/MyFolder/MyAppFolder/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols
- path of plist => /Users/yourhomefolder/Desktop/MyFolder/MyAppFolder/GoogleService-Info.plist
- /path/to/dSYMs : find path of dSYMs by following this answer => https://stackoverflow.com/a/11880813/8956604

/path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist : **No such file or directory**

/path/to/dSYMs : **No such file or directory**

Comment: Could you clarify your answer? I don't quite understand what you mean to do with each bullet point.

Comment: You should find these three paths correctly. Then you don't get this error.

Comment: Each path is correct on my end. What I tried in Terminal was combine all of the 3 paths like above which resulted in something looking like:  /PathToCrashlytics -gsp /PathToGoogleService.Info.plist -p ios /PathToDSYM but when I try to run it on terminal I get stopped with the issue above.

Comment: Yes, it should be like that. Any problems?

Comment: Unfortunately the terminal returns an error: -bash: cd:  Desktop/MyFolder/MyAppFolder/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols: Not a directory

Comment: Your path should be  /Users/your-pc-name/Desktop/MyFolder/MyAppFolder/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols

Comment: You can drag and drop upload-symbols to terminal